# Detect Debug or Release for Custom Configuration With Run Script

Tags: xcode, debugging, release, run-script

How could detect debug or release is running with build phases/run script?

I have four custom configuration each one duplicated from release or debug.

I found this answer but it doesn't work

```
    if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "Release" ]; then
       echo "Relese"
    else 
       echo "Debug"
    fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Assume these are custom configurations: `CustomDebug1`, `CustomDebug2`, `CustomRelease1`, `CustomRelease2`
Conditions should be on these configurations like this

```
PATH_TO_GOOGLE_PLISTS="${PROJECT_DIR}/MobileToken"

if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "CustomDebug1" ]; then
    echo "CustomDebug1"
fi

if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "CustomDebug2" ]; then
    echo "CustomDebug2"
fi

if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "CustomRelease1" ]; then
    echo "CustomRelease1"
fi

if [ "${CONFIGURATION}" = "CustomRelease2" ]; then
    echo "CustomRelease2"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Verify that you have set the correct configuration in the scheme settings:

[image: scheme settings]

Usually it is set to `Debug` in the Run step, but in this screenshot it is set to `Release` for the sake of example. Otherwise your script should work.

Comment: No I have some custom configurations, It solved, I edited my question, thanks.